# Portable way to "fork()" in Qt4 application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, fork

Say, I need to run a bunch of code that is prone to crash so I need to run it on a different process. Typically I'd do it like this:

```
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {
    std::cout << "Cant Spawn New Thread";
    exit(0);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    std::cout << "Im a child that will crash\n";
    char *foo = (char *) 0xffff;
    std::cout << foo;
    exit(0);
  } else {
    std::cout << "PID:  " << pid << "\n";
  }
  do {
    std::cout << "Waiting for " << pid << "  to finish .. \n";
    pid_w = waitpid(pid,&status,0);
  } while (pid_w == -1);
```

Obviously I can just use fork in my Qt4 application but I'm wondering if can I archive same functionality with any anything that Qt4 provides or any portable manner without resorting to having bunch of architecture `#ifdefs` ?

In any case, I'm targeting this app to have only `pthread` implementation but I'd still like to keep things as much close to "native" Qt API as possible.

I've tested `QThread`, and segfaulting in thread crashes the whole application obviously and it seems that `QProcess` is only targetted to be used when spawning completely different executables. Any other alternatives ?

Comment: Do you know there's a Qt forum at http://qtcentre.org? You can also ask on #qt channel on irc.freenode.net Just in case you don't get your answer here.

Comment: I did try to search possible examples from qtcentre's wiki but didnt find any, i'll drop by on #qt later today propably =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows flat-out doesn't have fork() in any publicly consumable way, so there's no Qt call to emulate it; you'll need to do something like start yourself with special command-line params or something.

Comment: Note that there is a way to emulate `fork()` on Windows. Cygwin does that. However, that is quite complicated and slow (it just copies the whole memory). So, the better way is probably to move the code out to an extra helper application which you can execute then in a subprocess. Or to start the same app with special command-line params as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should go with [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/threads.html#qtconcurrent) as it's the most high-level API for multithreaded programming available in Qt. This way your code will be more simple and cleaner.
As this is a high-level API it's probably implemented on top of lower-level APIs you already tried so this probably may not solve your problem, however.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried try...catch statements & figuring out how to avoid crashing????

Comment: Sorry but its not an option, the code that crashes *should* just crash if it wants to and my application should just catch that and just keep on ticking without crashing itself.

Comment: Trying to catch AVs and swallow them is a massive security vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

You might try [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) also.  It is older, and presumably less convenient than QtConcurrent.  It does not adjust automatically for the number of cores on a CPU, and thus does not distribute the work-load as evenly.  Still, it is probably the closest Qt analog to fork(), although it is not a drop-in replacement, and may work better for you.  Both are QThread and QtConcurrent are portable across platforms.